# Run Script When Link Opens - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write some Javascript that runs some code when a link to a product is clicked. Specifically, I am trying to write some which adds an item to my basket as soon as the product page opens (on [this website](http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all)). So clicking on an item from this page will open the product and automatically click the add to cart button.

To do this at the moment, I am currently using greasemonkey and running a script which clicks the add to cart button when the window opens (window.open) however it does not run as soon as the page opens; I have to open the page then reload it but I want the button to be clicked as soon as the page opens.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

There is method `window.onload` to be used like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //Your code here
}
```

or if you're in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Your code here
});
```

or (still JQuery):

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    //Your code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried doing this however I have to refresh the page before it carries out the script. Any ideas?

Comment: I might have more accurate suggestions if you included the code you're using now in your question.